# To connect to this server you must use SQL Server Management Studio or SQL Server Management Objects (SMO)

Tags: windows-server-2008, sql-server

I have 2 servers that are on different domains.

Server 1 - Windows Server 2003, SQL Server 2008
Server 2 - Windows Server 2008 R2

On Server 2 I have customer management software that connects to the SQL Server on Server 1. Server 2 is supposed to replace an older server.

Old Server - Windows Server 2003.

In the old setup the customer software was on Old Server and connected to Server 1 no problem (SQL Authentication). Now if I try to connect from Server 2 (customer software) to Server 1 (SQL Server) I get the following error.

> To connect to this server you must use SQL Server Management Studio or SQL Server Management Objects (SMO)

I have installed SSMS 2008, Connectivity SDK, and Compatibility Components on Server 2 as some websites suggested this was the problem. They did not help.

Note that on Server 2 I can successfully setup and test a DSN and connected via SSMS but just not with the software.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Can you connect to the sql server and run Select @@version and select compatibility_level from sys.databases’

Answer (score 0):

Did you try installing the **Microsoft SQL Server 2008 Management Objects Collections** ([from here)](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=c6c3e9ef-ba29-4a43-8d69-a2bed18fe73c) ?

That is the SMO (Shared Management Objects) that it mentions in the error message and it is the replacement for DMO which is part of 'Microsoft SQL Server 2005 Backward Compatibility Components' which I assume is what you have already tried.